# Does free() defragment?

Tags: c

Assuming two blocks allocated by malloc() that are internally next each other(who knows they next each other? just assumption), after free() two blocks, are they emerged into one unallocated block? Not sure, please help. Thanks.

Comment: yes, they will be combined together.

Comment: @Kenny. That's VERY implementation specifc, I really wouldn't assume anything. Depends on the OS etc

Comment: Can someone please give a OS or system that doesn't? I doubt one exists. Yes, in theory it's an implementation detail, but in reality software would run long without it.

Comment: @Kenny: this is not the only way to prevent disastrous memory fragmentation. For example for reasonably small allocations, allocate from a different heap according to the size of the allocation (increasing in powers of 2, say, up to a limit of perhaps 1k). Then you don't need to coalesce those smallish blocks. I don't know whether any malloc() implementations actually do this, but at least some JVMs do, so I wouldn't be at all surprised. You get better fragmentation-avoidance at the cost of some memory overhead up front (each heap's free cells can't be used for anything else).

Answer (score 12):

This fully depends on the implementation. Some allocators do consolidate, some do if certain conditions are met, some don't. It's not something you can assume in any way though. If this is an issue, find a solution that does not depend on such assumption (e.g manage a fixed pool yourself).

Comment: dlmalloc (pretty popular in some circles) seems to do it (or at least the implementation/version I just googled in front of me..) - I remember doing it myself for a videoram allocator. But well, bottom line is, that's not an assumption the client code should want to make :)

Comment: you might also be interested in nedmalloc which advertises itself as a little fragmentation memory manager -- it is based on dlmalloc, http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedmalloc/

Answer (score 3):

That depends entirely on the implementation of the allocator. There are [many different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc#Implementations) implmentations, [some of which](http://memoryallocators.com/research/allocators.html) perform coalescing of adjacent free memory.

**Edit:** Here's a [research paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.45.3382) that describes various allocation techniques and benchmarks their effect on fragmentation. I think their conclusion is that address-ordered free block lists (which make for easy coalescing) perform very well.

Comment: again question, how to an implementation has the ability of coalescing? cheers

Comment: @super newbie this should help 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation

Answer (score 2):

This is (very) implementation dependent. But if you want to do something about it, it's not free() you should be looking at but malloc(). Try not to allocate many small blocks.

Comment: Good comments, unfortunately my app does ask smaller piece of blocks frequently and this make me worried about the heap to be fragmented. so is it possible to know if my platform does'consolidate' ? thanks

Comment: I agree about the implementation however many heap allocators use multiple strategies i.e small, medium and large and often have a dedicated small object heap. For example XP has a 'Low Fragmentation Heap' strategy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366750(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That's a good one - alternatively you can choose to manage these smaller pieces of memory yourself, if that suits the context/scope.

Comment: super newbie, you would have to consult the docs for your library. You can add some platform info to your question.

Comment: zebrabox, the first level is always your C library, and your memory manager allocates from the OS.

Comment: That's debatable. It's perfectly sane to use the OS API directly in platform-specific parts of his implementation (if portability is an issue at all for the project at hand).

Comment: (though after looking into it I wouldn't advise in favor of enabling the LFH without serious consideration of other less invasive options :-))

Comment: @Henk Holterman. Under most conditions, I'd agree however we frequently implemented our own heap allocators in C on PlayStation 1 and PS2

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are algorithms commonly used which never coalesce adjacent memory.  But there are algorithms which don't do it as soon as two free blocks are adjacent but need some additional conditions.  Two examples:

- allocators using different memory regions depending on the asked size (for example which use special purpose datastructure for small blocks size so that they have less overhead)  will often not coalesce adjacent blocks for some sizes even if they use a more general algorithm for other sizes;
- buddy memory allocators will combines two blocks only if they are buddy.

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees, but many allocators do.  **If you have a performance problem involving memory**, you will get answers more to the point if you **pose that question directly**.  There are many, many techniques for improving memory performance of C code; it's a frequent bottleneck.